# PyTest: skip entire module/file (python 2 and 3)

Tags: python, pytest

I want to skip an entire test if imports don't work:

```
try:
  import networkx
except:
  import pytest
  pytest.skip()
```

This works fine with python-2.7 and python-3.5, both using pytest-2.8.1. When I try to run the code in python-3.6 with pytest-3.0.5 I get the following error:

> Using pytest.skip outside of a test is not allowed. If you are trying to decorate a test function, use the @pytest.mark.skip or @pytest.mark.skipif decorators instead.

How can I write code/tests that works on all mentioned environments? I already tried to rewrite the except block like this but then it only works for the newest configuration:

```
try:
  pytest.skip()
except:
  pytestmark = pytest.mark.skip
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

A more straightforward solution would be to use [pytest.importorskip](https://docs.pytest.org/en/stable/reference.html#pytest-importorskip-ref) instead.

Comment: This is also an elegant solution. I don't know how to specify, e.g. `from networkx.algorithms import bipartite` with `importorskip`, though.

Comment: `bipartite = pytest.importorskip("networkx.algorithms").bipartite` (or just do the import separately after `importorskip`)

Comment: That link mentions `skipif` instruction just below it.

Answer (score 21):

You can use [`pytest.skip`](https://docs.pytest.org/en/stable/reference/reference.html#pytest-skip) with `allow_module_level=True` to skip the remaining tests of a module:

```
pytest.skip(allow_module_level=True)
```

See example in: https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/how-to/skipping.html#skipping-test-functions

Answer (score 10):

I figured it out myself. The skip block needs to check the version of pytest:

```
if pytest.__version__ < "3.0.0":
  pytest.skip()
else:
  pytestmark = pytest.mark.skip
```

Comment: out of curiosity: Why do you need your testsuite to work with pytest 2.8.1 too?

Comment: I like my code to be as backward-compatible as possible and this was just the version I had installed on another machine.